# Azure SQL Database - Different IP Ranges Based on Authentication Type

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Hi I am interested users from public internet (all IP addresses) to access my Azure SQL Database if they are using Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA authentication but limit access to a specified list of IP addresses if using other authentication methods (i.e. SQL Server Authentication).

Is this possible? How can I implement it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is achievable, if we think about defense in depth, we're looking at two different layers. In your use case,  when the client is prompted for authentication or challenged with MFA, you already allowed the traffic through your resource firewall.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/security-overview?view=azuresql